# Instalar Laravel en Subcarpeta WebHosting

Tags: php, laravel

Hola que tal tengo un problema con laravel instalado en una subcarpeta.

Lo instale en midominio.com/web

La instalación salió perfecta, es decir, que si ingreso desde el navegador a midominio.com/web ingresa al index e inicializa todo correctamente, el problema está en la redirección. Por ejemplo. Cuando presiono "Inicio" es un button

```
<a href="/">Inicio</a>
```

Me redirecciona hacia midominio.com y así con todos los botones del sitio.

Estuve recorriendo todas las paginas que hablan sobre subcarpetas pero a nadie le pasó.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Tendrias que configurar el web server para que apunte al directorio `public` de tu proyecto laravel. Luego por el navegador ingresas directamente a tu dominio

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de un archivo de plantilla blade con extensión .blade.php puedes usar el helper `url()` de esta forma: `<a href="{{ url('/') }}">Inicio</a>`

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-url